# Why has $3^x+4^y=5^z$ has only one solution (2,2,2) in positive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

First, do we have to exclude the cases, where $(x,y,z)$ are not all even or odd and then show the only possibility ?

or is there a geometric solution maybe ?

Comment: I have a truly marvellous proof of this, but the answer box is too small to contain it.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571622/positive-integral-solutions-of-3x4y-5z