# Reference request: there are only two integer solutions to $2^{2a} + 3^{2b} = 5^c$.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I believe there are only two non-negative integer solutions to $$2^{2a} + 3^{2b} = 5^c.$$ The solutions I have are $a=1,b=0,c=1$ and $a=2,b=1,c=2$. I'm not certain this is correct. I'd like to know if there are other solutions, or if there a theorem that says these are the only solutions.

For further context, I'm generating Pythagorean triples as $$(r^2 - s^2, 2rs, r^2 + s^2)$$
where $r$ and $s$ are powers of $2$ or $3$. The solutions above correspond to the $(3,4,5)$ and $(7,24,25)$ Pythagorean triples.

Thanks for reading,

Daniel

Comment: How do you know that $c$ = an odd positive integer won't generate any solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. c=1 does correspond to a solution. I should have added that I can prove this myself when c is even, so it really is just the c="odd positive integer > 1" that I can't resolve.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I intended $c = $ an odd positive integer $> 1.$  Also, assuming that $c = 2d,$ then you have that $2^{(2a)} + 3^{(2b)} = 5^{(2d)} \implies$ that you do have a *primitive* pythagorean triplet $(x^2 + y^2 = z^2, ~~~x,y,z~$ pairwise comprime $)$.  This means that your $r,s$ specification holds.  I would like to see a proof that when $c$ is even, the only solutions are $(3,4,5), (7,24,25).$  If you can, please edit your query to show this proof.

Comment: Re my last comment, my bad again.  $(7,24,25)$ won't be a solution, so the *partial-assertion* is that when $c$ is even, the only solution is $(3,4,5)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positive integral solutions of $3^x+4^y=5^z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571622/positive-integral-solutions-of-3x4y-5z). Note $2^{2a} = 4^{a}$ so your equation could be written as $3^{2b} + 4^{a} = 5^{c}$. Also, although the proposed duplicate doesn't include the $b = 0$ solution, it otherwise actually answers a somewhat more general question than yours.

Comment: If $c=2d$ is even then $3^{2b}=5^{2d}-2^{2a}=(5^d-2^a)(5^d+2^a)$ so both factors on the right must be powers of $3$, but the gcd of the two terms on the right divides $2\times 5^d$ and $2^{a+1}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yes that will work provided we also assume the integers $x,y,z$ are positive. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: @user2661923 The solution suggested by John is more or less what I did. All I missed was that the power of $5$ had to be even.